# Getting error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: android, c++11, android-studio, stlport

I am trying to compile an android application in android studio (ndk r10d) which uses some C++ code. I needed C++11 so I added `-std=gnu++11` (I need `gnu++11` instead of `c++11` for an extension I am using). I am using the stlport stl, due to other libraries I am using that use this stl library.
So my cFlags and stl parameters in the build.gradle file looks like this:

```
stl "stlport_static"
cFlags " mylib1.a mylib2.a ... -fexceptions -frtti -std=gnu++11"
```

I also have included memory: `#include <memory>`

When trying to compile I receive this error:

```
'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

I have been using the boost implementation for the smart pointers till now but with the move to c++11 I would rather use the standard implementation.

Comment: What's the actual code that causes the error?

Comment: The original error is on this define I added to make code shorter but the errors are seen throughout the files wherever I try to use this macro: #define myapp_shared_ptr std::shared_ptr

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't name a type. It names a type template. Are you sure you're doing shared_ptr<T> when you use it? The error I get when I leave that out is "use of class template requires template arguments"

Comment: I don't think STLport has C++11 features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@T.C Looks like you were right. I saw your claim on a different question while looking for a solution for my problem, but as libraries that I am using are compiling with C++11 and STLport I thought that this claim might not be true.

What I think happened is that the libraries I'm using are not using any C++11 features that the STLport is missing. They are only using C++11 features that the gcc compiler supports. I need the gnuStl to support the features that I am using.

My solution was to use the boost implementation for the smart pointers and all other missing C++11 features.

Comment: Yes, GNU STL supports all C++11 features.

Answer (score 47):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared
use head file in your code.

```
#include <memory>
```

Comment: Is this necessary?

Comment: I had this same problem and shared_ptr is not defined in <memory> when using stlport_static. This answer is pointless.

Comment: #include <memory> worked for me.  The standard says that it is defined in <memory>

Comment: For me, this was necessary with g++ on Linux, but not msvc on Windows.

Comment: you don't need <iostream> above, just <memory>

Comment: worked for a similar error for 'auto_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Answer (score 1):

I got here googling for a similar error, but the answer did not work:

```
error: ‘shared_pointer’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
```

In my case, it was a typo:

```
std::shared_pointer
```

should be

```
std::shared_ptr
```